# JUnit: another pattern to test exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, exception, junit

I work on a project with many "BusinessException" that embedded errorCode.

In every unit test for exception, I have to test these error code repeating this kind of pattern:

```
@Test
public void zipFileReaderCtorShouldThrowAnExceptionWithInexistingArchive() {
    try {
        zfr = new ZipFileReader("unexpected/path/to/file");
        fail("'BusinessZipException' not throwed");
    } catch (BusinessZipException e) {
        assertThat("Unexpected error code", e.getErrorCode(), is(ErrorCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Unexpected Exception: '" + e + "', expected: 'BusinessZipException'");
    }
}
```

(use of JUnit annotation is impossible due to error code testing)

I was bored to do this, particularly because I had to copy/paste exception name in fail()'s error message.

So, I wrote a Util class. I use an abstract class to handle exception assert testing.

```
public abstract class TestExceptionUtil {
    public  void runAndExpectException(Class expectedException, String expectedErrorCode) {
        String failUnexpectedExceptionMessage = "Unexpected exception. Expected is: '%s', but got: '%s'";
        try {
            codeToExecute();
            fail("'" + expectedException.getName() + "' not throwed");
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            if (e.getClass().equals(expectedException)) {
                assertThat("Exception error code not expected", e.getErrorCode(), is(expectedErrorCode));
            } else {
                fail(String.format(failUnexpectedExceptionMessage, expectedException.getName(), e));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail(String.format(failUnexpectedExceptionMessage, expectedException.getName(), e));
        }
    }

    abstract public void codeToExecute();
}
```

Then, client use it in this way :

```
@Test
public void zipFileReaderCtorShouldThrowAnExceptionWithInexistingArchive() {
    new TestExceptionUtil() {
        @Override
        public void codeToExecute() {
            zfr = new ZipFileReader("unexpected/path/to/file");
        }
    }.runAndExpectException(BusinessTechnicalException.class, ErrorCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Do you think it's "clean" ? Do you think it can be ameliorated ? Do you think it's too heavy and/or useless?
My primary objective is to uniformize testing exception in our dev team. (and of course factorize code)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about the JUnit [`ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) [`Rule`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/Rule.html)?

First you declare the `Rule` at the top of the test class:

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException ee = ExpectedException.none();
```

Then in your test method you can declare that you can expect an `Exception`:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() {
    ee.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    ee.expectMessage("My Exception text");
}
```

I think this is significatly cleaner than your approach.

You can then use [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) [`Matcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html)s to match the `Exception` message:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() {
    ee.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    ee.expectMessage(containsString("error"));
    ee.expect(hasProperty("errorCode", is(7)));
}
```

The `hasProperty` `Matcher` will look for a getter for the named property and check that it matches the second argument - which is another `Matcher`.

You can even implement your own `Matcher`, in which case you will not require a dependency on hamcrest:

```
public class ErrorCodeMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Throwable> {

    private final int expectedErrorCode;

    public ErrorCodeMatcher(int expectedErrorCode) {
        this.expectedErrorCode = expectedErrorCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        return ((BusinessZipException) o).getErrorCode() == expectedErrorCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description d) {
        d.appendText("Expected error code was" + expectedErrorCode);
    }
}
```

This would be used as follows:

```
ee.expect(new ErrorCodeMatcher(7));
```

With a `static` factory method and a `static` import this can become quite clean:

```
ee.expect(exceptionWithErrorCode(7));
```

If you have a common `interface` that defines your business `Exception` with a `getErrorCode()` method, say called `ErrorAwareException` then you can extend the `TypeSafeMatcher<T>` class to create slightly cleaner code:

```
public class ErrorCodeMatcher<T extends Exception & ErrorAwareException> extends TypeSafeMatcher<T> {

    public static <E extends Exception & ErrorAwareException> ErrorCodeMatcher<E> exceptionWithErrorCode(final int expectedErrorCode) {
        return new ErrorCodeMatcher<E>(expectedErrorCode);
    }
    private final int expectedErrorCode;

    public ErrorCodeMatcher(int expectedErrorCode) {
        this.expectedErrorCode = expectedErrorCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final T t) {
        return t.getErrorCode() == expectedErrorCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description d) {
        d.appendText("Expected error code was" + expectedErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Note that if you do choose to use hamcrest then make sure that you include `junit-dep` rather than pure `junit` in your project otherwise the hamcrest classes will clash with the hamcrest classes included with `junit`. In maven, this will look something like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are actually reinventing the wheel here. You can use either `expected` parameter of the `@Test` annotation which causes test method to succeed of given exception was thrown. Or use the `ExpectedException` rule does basically the same but has more functionality. So try either

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void myTest() {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

or

```
@Rule
private ExpectedException rule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void myTest() {
    rule.expect(Exception.class);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: The OP needs more than just matching the exception by `class` - this is why the OP thought to resort so that homebrew solution.

Comment: yep junit rule is the best way to test exception. More info here https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/09/27/testing-exceptions-junit-47